# I have a embeddedId in a class and when i try to use mapStruct in the class it says that the property of the Id does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

I have a class named CompraProducto which one implements a embedded pKey and when i try to use mapStruct to translate the id it givme this error

> "No property named "idCompraProducto" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "idProducto"?"

> "Can't map property "int purchaseProductId" to "ComprasProductosPk idCompraProducto". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "ComprasProductosPk map(int value)""

i think it happens becouse the class where i try to map the id have the value of the id like a int not like a class

is my first time using maptruct so i don´t know what to do, becuse in the domain i want to have the value of the id like a int what can i do?

Here is the code of the class i try to map:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class CompraProducto {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ComprasProductosPk idCompraProducto;

    @Column(name = "id_compra")
    private Integer idCompra;

    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Integer idProducto;

    private Integer cantidad;

    private Double total;

    private Boolean estado;
```

Here is the code of the pk class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ComprasProductosPk implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id_compra")
    private Integer idCompra;

    @Column(name = "id_producto")
    private Integer idProducto;

    public Integer getIdCompra() {
        return idCompra;
    }

    public void setIdCompra(Integer idCompra) {
        this.idCompra = idCompra;
    }

    public Integer getIdProducto() {
        return idProducto;
    }

    public void setIdProducto(Integer idProducto) {
        this.idProducto = idProducto;
    }
}
```

Here is the class of the mapping class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PurchaseProductMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "idCompraProducto",target = "purchaseProductId"),
            @Mapping(source = "idCompra",target = "purchaseId"),
            @Mapping(source = "idProducto",target = "productId"),
            @Mapping(source = "cantidad",target = "amount"),
            @Mapping(source = "total",target = "total"),
            @Mapping(source = "estado",target = "active")
            /*
            @Mapping(source = "compra",target = "purchase"),
            @Mapping(source = "producto",target = "product")

             */

    })
    PurchaseProduct toPurchaseProduct(CompraProducto compraProducto);
    List<PurchaseProduct> toPurchasesProducts(List<CompraProducto> compraProductos);


    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    CompraProducto toCompraProducto(PurchaseProduct purchaseProduct);
}
```

And here is the code of the domain class:

```
public class PurchaseProduct {
    private int purchaseProductId;
    private int purchaseId;
    private int ProductId;
    private int amount;
    private double total;
    private boolean active;

    public int getPurchaseProductId() {
        return purchaseProductId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseProductId(int purchaseProductId) {
        this.purchaseProductId = purchaseProductId;
    }

    public int getPurchaseId() {
        return purchaseId;
    }

    public void setPurchaseId(int purchaseId) {
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return ProductId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        ProductId = productId;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to use the text `source = "idCompraProducto. idProducto"`?  not like this `source = "idCompraProducto"`

Comment: like this?: @Mapping(source = "idCompraProducto.idProducto",target = "purchaseProductId")

Comment: yes! did it work??

Comment: it doesn´t work it says that don´t exist a properti whit that name

Comment: perhaps.... CompraProducto class has a setter and getter?

Comment: i tink take the source like a string i also try whitout the quotation marks but when i try to instantiate the object CompraProducto i can´t becouse the mapper is a interface

Comment: you mean these ?:    public ComprasProductosPk getIdCompraProducto() {
        return idCompraProducto;
    }

    public void setIdCompraProducto(ComprasProductosPk idCompraProductod) {
        this.idCompraProducto = idCompraProducto;
    }

Comment: whould you like that i give you a git repository with the code ?

Comment: yep let me know I will try that

Comment: here you have https://github.com/franbz1/S

Comment: I couldn't see your domain directory in the repository

Comment: https://github.com/franbz1/S/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fundamentos/springboot/fundamentos/DOMAIN/PurchaseProduct.java

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this.
It works for me just plus the getter and setter.

you can see the generated class.

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2022-03-21T15:32:32+0900",
    comments = "version: 1.4.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-7.4.1.jar, environment: Java 11.0.11 (AdoptOpenJDK)"
)
@Component
public class PurchaseProductMapperImpl implements PurchaseProductMapper {

    @Override
    public PurchaseProduct toPurchaseProduct(CompraProducto compraProducto) {
        if ( compraProducto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PurchaseProduct purchaseProduct = new PurchaseProduct();

        Integer idProducto = compraProductoIdCompraProductoIdProducto( compraProducto );
        if ( idProducto != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setPurchaseProductId( idProducto );
        }
        if ( compraProducto.getIdCompra() != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setPurchaseId( compraProducto.getIdCompra() );
        }
        if ( compraProducto.getIdProducto() != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setProductId( compraProducto.getIdProducto() );
        }
        if ( compraProducto.getCantidad() != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setAmount( compraProducto.getCantidad() );
        }
        if ( compraProducto.getTotal() != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setTotal( compraProducto.getTotal() );
        }
        if ( compraProducto.getEstado() != null ) {
            purchaseProduct.setActive( compraProducto.getEstado() );
        }

        return purchaseProduct;
    }

    @Override
    public CompraProducto toCompraProducto(PurchaseProduct purchaseProduct) {
        if ( purchaseProduct == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CompraProducto compraProducto = new CompraProducto();

        compraProducto.setIdCompraProducto( purchaseProductToComprasProductosPk( purchaseProduct ) );
        compraProducto.setIdCompra( purchaseProduct.getPurchaseId() );
        compraProducto.setIdProducto( purchaseProduct.getProductId() );
        compraProducto.setCantidad( purchaseProduct.getAmount() );
        compraProducto.setTotal( purchaseProduct.getTotal() );
        compraProducto.setEstado( purchaseProduct.isActive() );

        return compraProducto;
    }

    private Integer compraProductoIdCompraProductoIdProducto(CompraProducto compraProducto) {
        if ( compraProducto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        ComprasProductosPk idCompraProducto = compraProducto.getIdCompraProducto();
        if ( idCompraProducto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Integer idProducto = idCompraProducto.getIdProducto();
        if ( idProducto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return idProducto;
    }

    protected ComprasProductosPk purchaseProductToComprasProductosPk(PurchaseProduct purchaseProduct) {
        if ( purchaseProduct == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ComprasProductosPk comprasProductosPk = new ComprasProductosPk();

        comprasProductosPk.setIdProducto( purchaseProduct.getPurchaseProductId() );

        return comprasProductosPk;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i find that file ?

Comment: if you are using gradle then, you would see the build directory `root/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/${package-name}/*`

Comment: i am using maven

Comment: then target folder! like this "root/target/~~~"

Comment: it dosen´t let me open the annotation file :(

Comment: im using windows and intelij

Comment: it looks like this: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13tCWQ9TSPLht_QzEYEvX1r7vYgRK6tIT?usp=sharing

Comment: I have browsed your repository and I have found your field names in any classes were wrong

Comment: can you check your field little by little? I mean just one Mapping annotation and then plus the annotation like this

Comment: and I hope you could follow the java convention. because we have to insert text in source and target in the mapping annotation.

Comment: could you open a googlemeet/discord with me and explainme better?

Comment: i share you my screen